# As a South African passport holder, what is the minimum time to expiry required if I wish to fly into the country

Tags: passport-renewals, south-africa, south-african-citizens

In more detail:

I live in the UK. I am a dual national (SA and UK) but according to SA law must enter and leave the country on my SA passport. Because of delays to renewing SA passports from the UK, I am looking to return to SA and renew my passport while I am there. I have two questions

1. my SA passport has less than a month to expiry - will I be allowed to enter SA with this being the case?
2. is there anyone here with knowledge of how long it is taking to get SA passports renewed from within SA?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know of any country that has a minimum passport validity for its own citizens. Why would they? For all they know you might be going to stay indefinitely.